# sqlalchemy database query timing out everytime

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-3.4

Hoping someone can help out!

python3.4

I have run the following script on the local machine that's hosting several mysql databases:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, inspect
username = ***
password = ***
port = '22'
database = db_name
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://' + username +':' + password + '@127.0.0.1:' + port + '/' + database)
```

Whatever I do from here on that interacts with the database, it will time out (with the same error every time). For example:

```
inspector = inspect(engine) or metadata.reflect(engine) (run separately)
```

will both return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.2.0b2dev-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1165, in _do_get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-1.2.0b2dev-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/sqlalchemy/util/queue.py", line 145, in get
    self.not_full.wait(remaining)
sqlalchemy.util.queue.Empty
/*whole bunch other error messages here*/
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I have also tried

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:port/database')
```

with the same results.

Many thanks!

Comment: Would seem that this could be caused by a multitude of issues: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html. Also, are your examples exact representations of your code. Because if they are, you're not forming your connection URL string using the variables you've defined. Instead, you're passing a string `'mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@127.0.0.1:port/database'` as the URL, which obviously will not work. Even if your username and password were "username" and "password", "port" is not a valid port number...

Comment: Also, 22 is an unusual port for MySQL. Usually SSH sits at that, and MySQL at 3306.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, however that's how my company has configured their database, I tried 3306 and I just get an error in trying to make the connection.

Comment: A wild guess, but maybe you're supposed to be SSH tunneling to the DB? Other than that I'm unfortunately out of ideas.

Comment: OK thanks, I'm using an ssh tunnel onto the localhost of the machine running mysql, I'm then running the python script from that machine. The machine is set to accept no requests for the database from anything other than localhost.